# Angular - NGXS problem with loading data before view

Tags: angular, ngxs, angular-state-managmement

Have you encountered a problem when you route to component and loading a table. But table is  empty without data.

I mean the component / table is displayed. Data as i can see are in state(seassion storage] and loaded. I am able to display them if i refresh the page.

By the way i could dispatch state before this component and my problem could be solved or use simple service with call on api. But this is not solution for me.

So my problem is = how could i display / load data before view?

My assets.state.ts

```
    @Action(SetDevice)
  async setDevice({ patchState, dispatch }: StateContext<DeviceDataModel>) {
    return await this.deviceListService.getData().subscribe((response: DeviceDataModel) => {
      console.log(response);
      patchState({
        data: response.data,
        dataSet: response.dataSet,
        offset: response.offset,
        size: response.size,
      });
      dispatch(new SetDeviceSuccess());
    });
  }
```

Component - set data into state and load them into table
some.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetDevice());
    this.getTableData();
  }

getTableData() {
    this.tableData = this.store.selectSnapshot(DeviceState.getDataDevice);
  }
```

some.component.html

```
 <dynamic-table
        style="width: 85%;"
        *ngIf="tableData"
        [tableData]="tableData.data"
        [tableColumns]="tableCols"
        [url]="'devicelist'"
      ></dynamic-table>
```

Thank you in advance for any help or idea.

Comment: Hello, this is not an answer. But in order to answer you, I want you to try it.
Can you replace `this.getTableData();` with `setTimeout(() => { this.getTableData();}, 2000);`

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU yes this is working. Finally after timeout the data are displayed. But is there a better approach ?

Comment: `this.store.dispatch(new SetDevice()).subscribe(()=> {this.getTableData();})`
Can you tell me if this works for you to write it as answer?

Comment: The answer from @Poul Kruijt is correct for how you'd want to structure your state with Observables.  What's not clear to me is that you are calling dispatch on `SetDevice` but not waiting for it to complete before loading table data - but the state code is referring to `SetAssets` ( a different action) so I don't see how devices and assets link together

Comment: I post different state, my mistake. But both are the same. There is only different name and Interface. 

And no, this answer not working for me.... the table is empty until i refresh page. So far, the only solution has been setTimeout, and that doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: Refresh the page? That would reset the state again back to default (unless you are using the state storage plugin). I can't see how `setTimeout` would be required though so something else is missing. If you can reproduce it in a stackblitz might be able to find the problem.

Comment: Yes i am using a storage plugin. I will provide stackblitz and post it. But first i neeed to finish my work.

So it means with refresh / reoad page. Data are displayed and state is not reset to default. If i close the page, browser - after that state is reseted. Its work fine. Only problem is with loading data and i don't get it too with that setTimeout. But its working...

Comment: No worries mate, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue with toPromise() and then(). I know its not a best aproceh. But now its working.

So I simply replace this code with code below.

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetDevice());
    this.getTableData();
  }

getTableData() {
    this.tableData = this.store.selectSnapshot(DeviceState.getDataDevice);

  }
```

First of all I display spinner and after receiving data I just hide spinner and display table thanks to .then()

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.store
      .dispatch(new SetAccount())
      .toPromise()
      .then((result) => {
       console.log(res);
       this.getTableData();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your data is not loaded yet when you call `selectSnapshot`. You are way better of using a `@Select` statement:

```
@Select(DeviceState.getDataDevice)
readonly tableData$!: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(new SetDevice());
}
```

and have your template use the `async` pipe:

```
<dynamic-table *ngIf="tableData$ | async as tableData"
   [tableData]="tableData.data"
   [tableColumns]="tableCols"
   [url]="'devicelist'">
</dynamic-table>
```

Besides that, your `@Action` handler is wrong as well, that's not how you use `async/await` and an Observable. You need to return the Observable from the action handler, to make sure that when the action completes, and you subscribe to the dispatch, it will be done by then:

```
@Action(SetAssets)
setWorkflows({ patchState, dispatch }: StateContext<AssetDataModel>) {
  return this.assetListService.getData().pipe(
    switchMap((response: AssetDataModel) => {
      patchState({
        data: response.data,
        dataSet: response.dataSet,
        offset: response.offset,
        size: response.size,
      });

      return dispatch(new SetDeviceSuccess());
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for some advice, but result is still same. I will get empty table and data are displayed only if i refresh page.

Screenschot: https://ibb.co/gVSqMFF

Comment: @DanielVágner then the issue is in your `dynamic-table` component

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `this.getTableData();` function before the data is loaded.

some.component.ts

```
    @Select(state => state.youdata) yourdata$: Observable<any>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.dispatch(new SetDevice()); 
     }
```

some.component.html

```
 <dynamic-table
            style="width: 85%;"
            *ngIf="tableData"
            [tableData]="tableData.data | async"
            [tableColumns]="tableCols"
            [url]="'devicelist'"
          ></dynamic-table>
```

Comment: Not working. So far, the only solution was use setTimeout

Comment: Will you accept setTimeout as an answer to your question or you are searching for another answer?

Comment: I'm trying to look for a better solution. Before using setTimeout. If a better solution exists ...

Comment: Can you try this `[tableData]="tableData.data | async"`?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, I have updated the answer.